# python : install logging module

Tags: python

I have python 3.5, tried to install logging package in PyCharm, I got an error:

> Error occured when installing package 'logging'
>   Make sure that you use a version of Python supported by this package. Currently you are using Python 3.5.

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!')
logging.info('I told you so')
```

UPDATE:

If it is included why I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alotfi/PycharmProjects/firstProj/logging.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\alotfi\PycharmProjects\firstProj\logging.py", line 2, in <module>
    logging.warning('Watch out!')
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'warning'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'installing' logging? It's a module in the standard library included in a base install....

Comment: I have exactly the same error when running exactly the same examples. I have no idea why the error occurred. 
This question shouldn't be closed. It is very clear. Why the error occurred if it is standard library?

Comment: you named your file `logging.py`, the interpreter is looking for an attribute `warning` in your file, not in the module you intended to import

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logging is a standard package for [python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) this means that there is no reason to install it.

Comment: APDATED my question, if it's included why I got that error ?

Comment: always the same :   AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'warn'

Comment: This answer explains nothing. The Logging module is a standard package and still running first example from documentation gives an error like logging wouldn't be installed. WHY?

Comment: Well, the real answer seems to be quite simple: @user1034127, @tomasz74: The original poster seems to have saved his example script as `logging.py`. That's why it fails. Never give a script the same name as an existing module. If you `import logging`, you just import your own script. Give it another name and cheer up.

Comment: @absurd, you are completely right. 

answer seems odd is simply because author modified question after I posted my answer.