# Error using python logging from Pydev

Tags: python, logging, pydev, aptana

I am using PyDev with Python 3.5 from Aptana installation. All worked fine until I decided to explore logging module, which I never used before. I started with new script from the tutorial:

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
logging.info('I told you so')  # will not print anything
```

in Pydev I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\Tomasz\workspace\basicLogging.py", line 7, in <module>
    logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'warning'
```

I searched and found questions like: [python : install logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848251/python-install-logging-module) with similar problem but no solution. 
Obviously the problem is not with installation. When I run exactly the same script from CMD I have correct output. 
At the moment it seems like Pydev gives me error on most of my scripts. If I come back to the code wich previously worked fine, now I have this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\workspace\piClientFullQt.py", line 15, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import qt_compat
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 273, in <module>
    class _CapturingHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'Handler'
```

I am not sure how this happened. 
If I do `print(sys.executable)` it gives the same path `C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python3.exe` in both cases, CMD running fine and Pydev giving error.

I have some problem with some python variables in Pydev (I think) but can't find how to fix it.

**EDIT:**
I look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595276/pydev-eclipse-python-interpreters-error-stdlib-not-found?rq=1) question and tried the answers

Location of python interpreter is correct and it looks like I have all libs what I need

```
C:\Users\Tomasz>python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
C:\Users\Tomasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages
```

And site-packages are already in System PYHONPATH

I tried Restore Defaults in Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Iterpreters -> Python Interpreter

**EDIT:**
Following @Samuel advise I try:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
logging.info('I told you so')  # will not print anything
```

and in PyDev I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tomasz\workspace\SCT2python\goodExamps\logging\basicLogging.py", line 3, in <module>
    logger = logging.getLogger()
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

It works fine if I run it in command line as a script!!

**EDIT: THE SOLUTION**
Thanks to @Samuel I figure out I made absolutely stupid mistake!
Before I started playing with the library I made a folder to keep my scripts and stupidly I called it "logging". Obviously renaming the folder solved the problem!

Comment: Looks like something overshadowing build-n logger lib. Do you have other modules called `logging` in your project? If not, go to declaration of `logging` and tell me which file is opened

Comment: @Samuel you are a star! I made so stupid mistake !

Comment: @Samuel You're a live saver. Was about to start pulling my hair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init your logger instance:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.warning('Watch out!') 
logger.info('I told you so')
```

Comment: It does not change anything. I still have an error: `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'`